# Can I force window to open on top of other windows when opened by keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows, shortcut-keys, window-manager

I use SpaceFM as my primary file manager on Ubuntu. I typically open folder directly by keyboard shortcuts, so, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> opens my Work folder.

Specifically, I use execute the command `spacefm -w /home/rasmus/Work/` by the above shortcut, with the `-w` ensuring that SpaceFM opens a new window.

However, this new window is not always open on top of the last active window on the workspace. This is rather annoying, as it means I sometimes have to "dig" for the newly opened window.

So, my question is: Is there something additional I can add to the executed command that will ensure that the fresh window is opened on top?

Alternative solutions to the same effect are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

As `spacefm` used single process. New command just pass signal to the running process and this creates the new window at level just above its last created window.

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

- **With function:** It has 1sec delay.

  ```
  sfm() { spacefm $* & pid=`pgrep spacefm | head -1`; sleep 1;  wmctrl -i -R `wmctrl -lp | grep " $pid" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }'` }
  ```

  1. Run `spacefm` with same arguments `$*` were passed to the function, `&` in background
  2. `pgrep spacefm | head -1` get PID of main process which is in the head then store it in `pid` variable
  3. `sleep 1` wait for new process to terminal, to avoid raise of two windows (I don't know why, try removing it)
  4. `wmctrl -lp` get window list `| grep " $pid"` filter related ones to `$pid`, `| tail -1` filter last line/window then `| awk '{ print $1 }'` filter out window id (WID) which is in the first column `$1`
  5. `wmctrl -i -R WID`  Move the window WID to the current desktop, raise the  window, and give it focus.
- **With alias:** This will raise 2 windows the new one on the top but simpler.

  ```
  alias sfm="wmctrl -i -R \`wmctrl -lp | grep ' $(pgrep spacefm)' | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }'\`; spacefm"
  ```

  1. `wmctrl -lp` get window list `| grep " $pid"` filter related ones to `spacefm`, `| tail -1` filter last line/window then `| awk '{ print $1 }'` filter out window id (WID) which is in the first column `$1`
  2. `wmctrl -i -R WID`  Move the window WID to the current desktop, raise the  window, and give it focus.
  3. Run `spacefm` with arguments coming after. The new window will be created on the top.

**- How to use:** similar way to the original command.

```
    sfm -w /home/rasmus/Work/
```

**References:** Please look for the `man` pages.

Answer (score 0):

*It's an old question but still relevant, so I'll add an alternative solution.*

This sounds like a result of Compiz' focus prevention, trying to prevent windows from "stealing" focus while you're working somewhere else.

Focus prevention can be set to different levels (default: low) or completely disabled through CompizConfig Settings Manager.

If not installed yet, do this by running:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then, run it with `ccsm`, navigate to **General Options**, switch to the tab **Focus & Raise Behaviour** and change the field **Focus Prevention Level** (in your case, you'll probably want *Off*).